# javascript regex for 2 possible values

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble coming up with a regex to accept two possible values.

I would like to accept a % or a number and unit.

For example.
Any percentage between 0% and 100% are acceptable.
OR
Any integer followed by a suffix.  (10 AB, 78JB, 244 AB).
Only possible suffixes are (AB, JB, RB, LB, IB)

Value must be one or the other (2% OR 10 AB);

I can do these individually with regex but don't know how to combine into one.

```
\d+\s?(AB|JB|RB|LB|IB)?
\d+\s?\%
```

Comment: Group the two regexes and use OR `|` to match either!

Comment: ah....duh....i was trying to share the digits part...but that approach works as well. Thx.

Comment: Are the suffixes to be matched as whole words? I.e. do you need to match `10 AB` in `10 ABC`? Try [`/\d+\s?(?:(?:AB|JB|RB|LB|IB)\b|%)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/rq7thr/1)

Comment: So simple `\d+\s?(?:%|AB|JB|RB|LB|IB)` combine and conquer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to "merge" the patterns so as to only repeat the `\d+` part once, you may just include the `%` into the alternation group with letter suffxies:

```
/\d+\s?(?:AB|JB|RB|LB|IB|%)/g
```

(see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VopDoZ/1)) *unless* you need to match the suffixes as whole words. In that case, you need to add a word boundary after the suffixes only, not after `%`:

```
/\d+\s?(?:(?:AB|JB|RB|LB|IB)\b|%)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rq7thr/1)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can just add an OR statement between the two:

```
\d+\s?(AB|JB|RB|LB|IB)|\d+\s?\%
```

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/pFoRI9/1). I removed a `?` after the 'number unit'.